# How to implement a strongSwan killswitch on Linux?

Tags: strongswan

I am using PF as the killswitch on macOS (see [this](https://sunknudsen.com/privacy-guides/setting-up-your-very-own-macos-kernel-level-ikev2-ipsec-vpn-kill-switch-using-pf)).

Using PF is possible because the ipsec connection has it’s own interface (ipsec0).

How can I implement something similar on Linux given the ipsec connection is on the same interface as ethernet?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are searching for something like `nftables` or `iptables` or any firewall sitting on top of these like `firewalld` or `ufw`.

Answer (score 0):

Using Netfilter's *policy* module you can easily create firewall rules that apply to tunneled or non-tunneled traffic. For instance, to reject all outbound traffic that doesn't match any IPsec policies (i.e. is not tunneled) you could use a rule like this:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m policy --pol none --dir out -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-admin-prohibited
```

Alternatively, you can block all outbound traffic by default (e.g. set the policy for the `OUTPUT` chain to `DROP`) and then use the following to explicitly allow tunneled traffic:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m policy --pol ipsec --dir out -j ACCEPT
```

If necessary, these rules can be made more specific (e.g. limited to certain interfaces or IP addresses).

In both cases you'll need additional rules to allow IKE (UDP 500/4500) and ESP traffic (protocol 50, or the same ports as IKE if UDP encapsulation is used), plus DNS (unless the VPN server IP is hard-coded) and possibly DHCP.